# xslt printing issue using for-each and param

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to format this piece of xml to the required output.

**Input xml:**

```
<Damage>
    <MachineryItems>
        <MachineryItemDisplayBean>
            <itemNumber>1</itemNumber>
            <additionalCoverBasis>MD</additionalCoverBasis>
        </MachineryItemDisplayBean>
        <MachineryItemDisplayBean>
            <itemNumber>2</itemNumber>
            <additionalCoverBasis>MP</additionalCoverBasis>
        </MachineryItemDisplayBean>
        <MachineryItemDisplayBean>
            <itemNumber>3</itemNumber>
            <additionalCoverBasis>MC</additionalCoverBasis>
        </MachineryItemDisplayBean>
    </MachineryItems>
</Damage>
```

This is the xml based on which the formatting needs to be done:
there are multiple `<MachineryItemDisplayBean>` under the `<MachineryItems>`.

If any one of the `<MachineryItemDisplayBean>` has value MP under`<additionalcoverbasis>` then Y needs to be printed else if none of the `<MachineryItemDisplayBean>` has value MP under`<additionalcoverbasis>` then N needs to be printed

Output for the previous input xml should be:

```
Y
```

**XSL used:**

```
<xsl:template match="Damage/MachineryItems">
    <xsl:param name="DMFlag" select="'N'">
    <xsl:for-each select="MachineryItemDisplayBean">
        <xsl:if test="MachineryItemDisplayBean/additionalCoverBasis = 'MP'">
             <xsl:value-of select="'Y'"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="$DMFlag"/>
    </xsl:param>
</xsl:template>
```

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet

Comment: no value displayed when using this xsl , i have also tried using Variable instead of the param but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If any one of the `<MachineryItemDisplayBean>` has value MP
>   under`<additionalcoverbasis>` then Y needs to be printed else if none of
>   the `<MachineryItemDisplayBean>` has value MP
>   under`<additionalcoverbasis>` then N needs to be printed

I believe that translates to:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Damage/MachineryItems/MachineryItemDisplayBean/additionalCoverBasis[.='MP']">Y</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>N</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, works like a gem, sorry cant upvote due to lack reputations

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with your stylesheet:

- an `xsl:param` or `xsl:variable` whose value is never used has no effect (and the XSLT library could even avoid evaluating it)
- if you create either `Y` or `N` for each `MachineryItemDisplayBean` element, at the end you will have something like `NYN`

A couple of ways to achieve what you need:

**Solution 1:** two templates, only one will match

```
<xsl:template match="Damage[MachineryItems/MachineryItemDisplayBean/additionalCoverBasis = 'MP']">
    Y
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Damage[not(MachineryItems/MachineryItemDisplayBean/additionalCoverBasis = 'MP')]">
    N
</xsl:template>
```

**Solution 2:** a single template

```
<xsl:template match="Damage">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="MachineryItems/MachineryItemDisplayBean/additionalCoverBasis = 'MP'">
            Y
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            N
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: "*an xsl:param ... cannot contain a sequence constructor*" Where did you get this idea? http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#parameters

Comment: @michael.hor257k TIL: `xsl:param` *can* contain a sequence constructor. Thank you very much: lesson learned, answer amended.

Comment: Thanks Ifurini for the help